# htaccess changing PHP version from 5.3 to 5.5 causing an index.php download

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5

I just want to ask what is the possible solution for this kind of error. I'm using Laravel 5.2 but the Cpanel PHP version is not suitable for this framework, the Cpanel PHP version is 5.3. So I have to add a code in htaccess to change the PHP version of the server, however it causes an index.php download.

This is the code I inserted in htaccess:

```
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well, have you installed PHP 5.5, with a defined handler for `x-httpd-php55` types...? The reason it downloads is because you're telling Apache that .php files are "application/x-httpd-php55" files, and Apache has no idea what to do with that kind of file.

Comment: I suspect this is as simple as the server not knowing what `application/x-httpd-php55` is, and simply passing the file directly. Are you sure php 5.5 is available on the server?